# can mechanize read ajax? (ruby)

Tags: ruby, ajax, mechanize, web-scraping

can I get the correct data/text that is displayed via AJAX using mechanize in ruby?

Or is there any other scripting gem that would allow me to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mechanized cannot read data displayed by JavaScript, because it does not implement a JavaScript engine (in other words, it can't run it). You'll need a browser to do that, or a program that automates a browser to do it for you. [WATIR](http://watir.com/) is one such program.

Comment: FRKT: I thought that it would be like that :-( but I cannot run browser/WATIR on my linode.com - I guess - or can I?

Comment: @Radek: I don't know, sorry - you'll have to get in touch with linode and ask them. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use WATIR with webdriver which is a console only, headless browser.