# Scraping ajax enabled webpages

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, scrapy, mechanize, watir

I need to scrape career pages of multiple companies(with their permission).

Important Factors in deciding what do I use

1. I would be scraping around 2000 pages daily, so need a decently fast
   solution
2. Some of these pages populate data via ajax after page is loaded.
3. My webstack is Ruby/Rails with MySql etc.
4. I have written scrapers earlier using scrapy(python) (+ Selenium for ajax enabled pages).

My doubts

1. I am confused whether I should go with python (i.e. scrapy + Selenium, I think this is the best alternative in python), or instead prefer something in ruby(as my entire codebase is in ruby).
2. Scrapy + selenium is often slow, are there faster alternatives in ruby?(this would make the decision easier) Most popular Ruby alternative with support for Ajax Loaded pages seems to be **Watir** Can anybody comment on its speed. Also are there any other ruby alternatives (e.g. **Mechanize/Nokogiri** + *something else for Ajax Loaded pages*)

**EDIT**

Ended up using Watir-webdriver + Nokogiri, so that I can take advantage of active record while storing data. Nokogiri is much faster than Watir-webdriver at extracting data.

Scrapy would have been faster, but the speed tradeoff wasn't as significant as the complexity tradeoff in handling different kind of websites in scrapy (e.g. ajax-driven search on some target sites, which i have to necessarily go through).

Hopefully this helps someone.

Comment: This might not fit your use case, but for AJAX pages with Mechanize/Nokogiri, what you can do is refresh that page every 5-10 seconds. Though it isn't ideal and depending on the frequency you require, you can get any data that is loaded through those JS calls.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you are saying is right. I think mechanize/Nokogiri dont have javascript interpreters (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852678/can-mechanize-read-ajax-ruby)

Comment: They don't, but even if data is pushed to a table after an interval. As long as that data is persisted in the table, if you simply re-get the page you'll be able to scrape it. You would just need to verify from a browser, that after the page's data is populated via AJAX that if on a refresh of the page, the data is still there. That is something you can use Mechanize/Nokogiri to scrape, but you'd need to re-load that page.

Comment: Why not reproduce the ajax requests in scrapy? Unless is very difficult, that is an acceptable method to scrape websites with ajax requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If speed is important, you can use [watir-webdriver](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver) gem to drive [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) (headless browser with JavaScript support). Open any page in PhantomJS, and if watir-webdriver is too slow to get the data out of it, you can pass the rendered HTML to [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/).

Read more:

- http://jkotests.wordpress.com/2013/08/21/watir-nokogiri-gem-published/
- http://zeljkofilipin.com/watir-nokogiri/

Comment: still reading up on links you mentioned. the last link leads to an expired domain, you should renew it.

Comment: Ended up using watir-webdriver + nokogiri, although not the gem, as I preferred some flexibility for future.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out this guide [Making AJAX Applications Crawlable](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/) published by Google,
it discusses the AJAX crawling scheme which some website support.

You want to look for `#!` in the URL's hash fragment, this indicates to the crawler that the site supports the AJAX crawling scheme and that the server will return a HTML snapshot of the page when URL is slightly modified.

[Full Specification](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification)

Comment: Thanks for the guide (will help me if I build ajax powered apps which i want to be scraped by google). Unfortunately not all of my target sites follow this.